# C++ optional vs throw

Tags: c++

The use of optional is more likely when the return value may or may not exist is expected.
Exception in other hand is used when something 'unexpected' happens and need to be catch to prevent the system crashes.

Beside the functionality and elegance of these options and focusing only in performance, which code has a better performance in the naïve examples below?

Important to note in my project a Key will be find always, if not I have a big inconsistency and the program need to take several actions...

Optional example:

```
optional<MyObject> LookUp(const string& Key) {
    if (Key_found())
        return theObj;
    else
        return {};
}

int main() {
    ...
    while(true) {
        ...
        optional<MyObject> MyObj = LookUp(Key);
        if (MyObj)
            //work with MyObj
        else
            FixInconcistency();
    }
}
```

Throw example:

```
 MyObject LookUp(xonst string& Key) {
     if (Key_found())
        return the Obj;

     throw;                              //Just throw without any information
 }

 int main() {
     ...
     while(true) {
         ...
         try {
             MyObject MyObj = Lookup(key);
             //work with MyObj
         } catch (...) {
             FixInconcistency();
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: It's less a question of performance but getting the semantics correct.

Comment: A `throw;` that is not within an exception handler is quite performant, since `std::terminate` is called promptly. And beyond that, C++ exceptions should not be used for regular control flow. If a key not being found is a possible normal occurrence, it's not something for an exception.

Comment: When in doubt about performance: *measure*. And when measuring, don't forget to turn on optimization in your compiler (the `-O2` flag on Linux, release mode on Windows), otherwise you will get meaningless results.

Comment: Completing @user4815162342 You should use "-O3" in GCC/Clang.

Comment: Have you considered whether the performance of `work with MyObj` differs in the two cases?

Comment: @JohnTortugo `-O3` should be measured only if it is also used in production builds, which is not typical. On Linux `-O2` is used by default to build packages - for example, on Debian and Ubuntu, `dpkg-buildflags` outputs `-g -O2` optimization/debug flags, and the same [seems to apply](http://rpm5.org/docs/api/config_macros.html) for RPM. I'm not sure about the current reasons for that, but historically `-O3` was discouraged due to code bloat (and resulting instruction cache misses) from its more aggressive loop unrolling and call inlining.

Comment: If an exception happens so often that it actually impedes performance, then it either shouldn't be an exception in the first place, or the execution environment of the application is unfit for its purpose (too little memory, too many filesystem race conditions, etc.).

Comment: @user4815162342: Or more generally: measure what you will ship to the end user.

Comment: @ user4815162342 if you only concern is performance you should go for O3. Usually it is not applied for common production scenario because it may have some non-desirable side effects as you mentioned.

Comment: `throw ` uses better semantics; you return a value the usual way and you can decide *where* you want to handle the unexpected case. Also almost all implementations are as fast as if there was no exception. The slow thing is throwing and not entering a try block

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, the different between the two versions is in the code's meaning, rather than its performance. I understand from the question you are already aware of it, so I'm going to answer the question as asked.

Which one better performs greatly depends on the probability of `Key_found` returning `false`.

Exceptions in C++ were built with one goal in mind - make the non-throwing case as cheap as possible, under the understanding that they are thrown in circumstances that are, well, exceptional.

As such, if the probability of `Key_found` is really low, the extra overhead of returning a compound type over a simple one would make the second form cheaper (assuming, that is, that `MyObject` is, indeed, simple. Otherwise, there should be little difference).

If, on the other hand, the probability of `Key_found` is not so low, the cost of repeatedly unwinding the stack would be much higher.

As usual, the best answer is to benchmark.

As a side note, the main advantage of exceptions is that you do not have to explicitly handle the exceptional case inline, and you do not need to propagate it through unwinding. Using it in the way you do here makes little sense.

Also, the throwing sample has a bunch of problems. In particular, throwing nothing doesn't do what you think it does, and a `catch(...)` without rethrowing is a *really* bad idea.

Comment: That is exactly the point... it is expected to find a key always...  in my project, if a key wasn't found than I have a big inconsistency and several actions need to be taken. Can you explain a little bit more about why throw nothing and catch (...) is a bad idea?

Comment: Throw nothing calls `terminate`. You might as well just call assert to terminate if the key is not found (which might actually be a good idea). catch(...) catches stuff that need never be caught, such as the exception used by pthreads to terminate threads on `pthread_cancel`.